# Java File Corruption issue

Tags: java, file, file-io, aix, corruption

I have a java application which is doing a lot of file operations. For each file processing (task) I will open one log4j file for writing the task log.  In each task I am opening one file and doing some manipulation and writing into a three new files. Tasks are running in parallel.  Now Randomly once in two weeks or three weeks my task log files are going into data file (not completely always, data and logs are writing in mix into the new data files) .

We have reviewed the code, and are not able to find any synchronization issue or FileDescriptor reuse.

OS : AIX 6.1.6.3
JAVA : IBM JAVA 1.5 SR12 FP1
Architecture : Power 6; 8 core with SMT on
Storage : SAN

Thanks 
Nikesh PL

Comment: I don't think anyone would be able to diagnose this without looking at the code.  And by the sounds of it, there's too much code to expect someone on SO to look at ... for free.  I suggest you try and find a Java concurrency expert who you can pay to review your code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! It may not be completely code issue. It can be some thing like this http://256.com/gray/docs/misc/java_bad_file_descriptor_close_bug.shtml also.

Comment: Hmmm ... notice that that the cited Sun bug is marked as "fix delivered" in Sun Java in 5_u14 & 6_u4. I suggest you contact IBM support and ask which version of Java 1.5 for AIX / Power has that bug fix in it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure you flush() then close() your files input streams (or files readers) in a try/finally block?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes, we have verified that.